# How to make *.py files have the python icon in Win7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, ironpython, file-type, root

Installed the IronPython tools for VS 2010 but it didn't associate the *.py files to VS, neither did it (obviously) change the *.py files' icon.
How do I do that in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either go to `Tools -> Folder Options -> File Types` dialog from Windows Explorer or you use the freeware [Detault Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com) utility.

Comment: Sounds fair enough. If you have a nice icon file for *.py, please include in your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! if you have more ideas post them as well! that link is anyway a good useful link for any dev looking for icons!

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue. Here is what I did.

1. Right click on a python program.
2. Select properties.
3. You will find "opens with" option in the general tab.
4. Click change and select "python.exe".

Now, you will have your python icons back for all .py type of files.

Comment: I can see this changing the icon, but now it executes the file when I click it instead of opening it with my editor.  Hopefully the icon could be changed without messing up other things.

Comment: If you want to open it in a editor, you have to open your editor first, and then open the program from open icon in the editor. @Diego

Comment: I know how to open a file with a specific application.  I just don't like its icon linked to the program to _open with_, instead of the filetype associated to the extension.